Is “bonding event" the best term for an event at which people can bond with each other?
I'm struggling to come up with a word that means an event where we can bond with each other, not just for a team or a company division, but maybe for family members or people in the same community, etc.
I searched for "a bonding event," but there weren't many results for this phrase. I also tried to find a phrase describing such event, but the phrase "team building events" seemed to get more hits on google search.
Is there any phrase/word describing an event where we (as people in a family/community/circle of friends/...) can bond?

bonding for a company event is not a good choice of word. develop relationships with each other is less marked.

It's going to depend on whether it's introducing strangers or strengthening bonds between people who know each other. Or you could say something really vague like "social event".

I wouldn't use any special term.
In a company you have people who have nothing particularly in common, whom the company wants to get to work effectively together.  The employees haven't chosen to work together, they have been selected by the company. Hence the need to build "teams".  And such events are in contrast to the usual coming together to work.  Therefore a special term exists "team building event"
But if you are family, you already have that connection.  If you are a circle of friends you come together to be friends.  "Bonding" is implied. So no special term is needed.
You can use any of the normal expressions "A party", "A get-together",  "An evening out", "a gathering".  Some of these colocate well with particular situations: "A family party", "An evening out with friends", "A community gathering".  (But don't think that "a family gathering" etc is wrong)

I think describing something as a bonding event is perfectly acceptable if it's an event where people bond with each other. For example, you might have a group hug at the event.

May God protect me from ever having to go to a 'bonding event'!

One term you might consider is ‘quality time’, as in ‘to spend some quality time with’ the relevant people.
One of Wiktionary's definitions covers friends as well as family:

Time spent enjoyably with family, friends, or one's partner.

And Cambridge Dictionary's definition clearly describes bonding:

time that you spend with someone, giving them your full attention because you value the relationship

(Wikipedia's page on the term suggests that it originated in the USA a half-century ago; I think it'd be widely understood now.)
